# Numpy, Reading from File with no delimiter but fixed pattern

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I tried searching for this question but I could not find answers that did not seem too complicated.

I am reading from a file that only has space delimiters. The columns are not fixed width. The first two columns are what are giving me the issue. It is 15 columns, where the first two are strings and everything else are floating numbers.

I try using numpy's "genfromtxt" and specified the dtype. However, some of the string entries are empty or contain numbers, so so lines are misread as having 15 or 17 entries.

Here is an example of a few lines lines.

```
NGC 104    47 Tuc       00 24 05.67  -72 04 52.6   305.89  -44.89    4.5   7.4   1.9  -2.6  -3.1
NGC 288                 00 52 45.24  -26 34 57.4   152.30  -89.38    8.9  12.0  -0.1   0.0  -8.9
NGC 362                 01 03 14.26  -70 50 55.6   301.53  -46.25    8.6   9.4   3.1  -5.1  -6.2
Whiting 1               02 02 57     -03 15 10     161.22  -60.76   30.1  34.5 -13.9   4.7 -26.3
```

How should I approach this? Should I reformat the text by rereading it and then outputting it as a CSV? Should I read as a regex? Can I fix this command:

`data = np.genfromtxt('PositionalData.txt', skiprows=0, missing_values=(' '), dtype=['S6','S6', 'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4', 'f5','f4','f4', 'f4', 'f4', 'f4', 'f4'])`

Thanks, help would be much appreciated.

edit:

Here is some output after using some fixed-width setting:

```
(' NG', 'C 1', 0.0, 4.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 4.0, 7.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
(' NG', 'C 2', 8.0, 8.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
(' NG', 'C 3', 6.0, 2.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
(' Wh', 'iti', nan, nan, nan, 1.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
(' NG', 'C 1', 2.0, 6.0, 1.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
(' Pa', 'l 1', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan)
```

The Command is `data = np.genfromtxt('PositionalDataTest.txt', skiprows=0,delimiter=(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), missing_values=(' '), dtype=['S7','S7', 'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4',  'f4', 'f5','f4','f4', 'f4', 'f4', 'f4', 'f4'])`

The lines are:

```
NGC 104    47 Tuc       00 24 05.67  -72 04 52.6   305.89  -44.89    4.5   7.4   1.9  -2.6  -3.1
NGC 288                 00 52 45.24  -26 34 57.4   152.30  -89.38    8.9  12.0  -0.1   0.0  -8.9
NGC 362                 01 03 14.26  -70 50 55.6   301.53  -46.25    8.6   9.4   3.1  -5.1  -6.2
Whiting 1               02 02 57     -03 15 10     161.22  -60.76   30.1  34.5 -13.9   4.7 -26.3
NGC 1261                03 12 16.21  -55 12 58.4   270.54  -52.12   16.3  18.1   0.1 -10.0 -12.9
Pal 1                   03 33 20.04  79 34 51.8   130.06   19.03   11.1  17.2  -6.8   8.1   3.6
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with numpy, but looking at the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), it can take parameter `delimiter` with a sequence of integers as the position of each field.

Comment: This is some of the worst formatting ever.  Since we have space-delimited values, if you are so unfortunate as to have an empty field is there any way of knowing which field is empty without physically looking at the data?  EDIT: I suspect Pandas can do this nicely...though missing fields in space-delimited files is still problematic.

Comment: @tnknepp Do you have any suggestions on where I can find this info? What I ended up doing was just delete all the string info I didn't need, but the files I am getting are formatted this way for some reason. So if you know what I can look up to get better equipped for these kind of files, thank you in advance.

Comment: In your example, which values correspond to "the first two columns"?  In `NGC 104    47 Tuc       `, are you trying to separate `NGC 104` and `47 Tuc`?  Is `Whiting 1` supposed to be a single value in the first column, or is that `Whiting` and `1`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You are correct in the latter. `NGC 104` and `47 Tuc` is the correct separation.

Comment: Are you sure this is space delimited and not tab delimited?

Comment: @tnknepp I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this portion of the data file:

```
-72 04 52.6 
-26 34 57.4 
-70 50 55.6 
-03 15 10   
-55 12 58.4 
79 34 51.8
```

It can be parsed like this:

```
In [75]: np.genfromtxt('data2', delimiter=[3,3,5], dtype=None).tolist()
Out[75]: 
[(-72, 4, 52.6),
 (-26, 34, 57.4),
 (-70, 50, 55.6),
 (-3, 15, 10.0),
 (-55, 12, 58.4),
 (79, 34, 51.8)]
```

The rest of the file could be parsed similarly, the difficulty is in finding the right column widths to use in `delimiter`.

That's laborious, and I'd rather not do that because this solution is fragile.
It is quite possible your data truly is not parseable using fixed-width columns.

So instead let's shoot for a robust solution. `np.genfromtxt` can accept any iterable of strings as its first argument.
So we can bring the full power of Python string manipulation to bear on the problem by simply defining a generator function to pre-process the lines from the file.
The price we pay for all this power is that calling a Python function once per line will be much much slower than the C code `np.genfromtxt` uses when parsing files with a simple delimiter or fixed-width columns.

```
import numpy as np
def process(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        parts = [line[:11], line[11:24]] + line[24:].split()
        yield '@'.join(parts)
with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    data = np.genfromtxt(process(f), dtype=None, delimiter='@')

print(repr(data))
```

yields

```
array([ ('NGC 104    ', '47 Tuc       ', 0, 24, 5.67, -72, 4, 52.6, 305.89, -44.89, 4.5, 7.4, 1.9, -2.6, -3.1),
       ('NGC 288    ', '             ', 0, 52, 45.24, -26, 34, 57.4, 152.3, -89.38, 8.9, 12.0, -0.1, 0.0, -8.9),
       ('NGC 362    ', '             ', 1, 3, 14.26, -70, 50, 55.6, 301.53, -46.25, 8.6, 9.4, 3.1, -5.1, -6.2),
       ('Whiting 1  ', '             ', 2, 2, 57.0, -3, 15, 10.0, 161.22, -60.76, 30.1, 34.5, -13.9, 4.7, -26.3),
       ('NGC 1261   ', '             ', 3, 12, 16.21, -55, 12, 58.4, 270.54, -52.12, 16.3, 18.1, 0.1, -10.0, -12.9),
       ('Pal 1      ', '             ', 3, 33, 20.04, 79, 34, 51.8, 130.06, 19.03, 11.1, 17.2, -6.8, 8.1, 3.6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S11'), ('f1', 'S13'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<i8'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<f8'), ('f9', '<f8'), ('f10', '<f8'), ('f11', '<f8'), ('f12', '<f8'), ('f13', '<f8'), ('f14', '<f8')])
```

Note that the `process` function uses `'@'` as the delimiter between columns. If the data contains `'@'` you will have to choose some other character for the delimiter.

Comment: The columns aren't fixed width.

Comment: The data you posted looks like it is fixed width. If it isn't, please post some lines which shows the problem (and, if it isn't obvious, what the desired output should be.)

Comment: Wow this solution works perfectly. Thank you very much. I don't really understand the `[line[:11], line[11:24]] + line[24:]` portion. How exactly does that work?

Comment: The best way to understand it is to play with an example in an iteractive session. Take `line = 'NGC 104    47 Tuc       00 24 05.67  -72 04 52.6   305.89  -44.89    4.5   7.4   1.9  -2.6  -3.1'` for example. `line[:11]` is the substring consisting of the first 11 characters. `line[11:24]` is the substring of the next 24-11 = 13 characters. `line[24:].split()` is the remainder of the line split on whitespace. `[line[:11], line[11:24]` is a list. `line[24:].split()` is a list. The sum of two lists is a new list, with the items concatenated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a similar approach in the future. If I could upvote your answer, I would!